# Balancing text overlay of images with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a row with three images and text overlaying them. I can't seem to get the left and right sides of the text balanced in separate sections. It should look like this:

[image]

I'm able to get the text on the left set correctly, but can't balance the text on the right and set a vertical pipe between the sections, with a right or left border.

```css
     .practice-areas {
      h1 {
        font-weight: 600;
        font-size: 60px;
        font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed';
        text-transform: uppercase;
        color: #ffffff;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 10%;
        left: 50%;
        -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
        transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
      }
      h5 {
        text-transform: uppercase;
        color: #ffffff;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 10%;
        left: 65%;
        -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
        transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
      }
      p {
        font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed';
        font-size: 20px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        color: #ffffff;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 10%;
        left: 55.4%;
        -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
        transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
      }
      .result {
        color: $grey;
        bottom: 7%;
        font-size: 16px;
        right: 38%;
      }
      .square-1 {
        background-image: url('https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&w=350&h=150');
        background-size: cover;
        height: 413px;
        @include breakpoint(xsmin) {
          height: 213px;
        }
      }
      .square-2 {
        background-image: url('https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&w=350&h=150');
        background-size: cover;
        height: 413px;
        @include breakpoint(xsmin) {
          height: 213px;
        }
      }
      .square-3 {
        background-image: url('https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&w=350&h=150');
        background-size: cover;
        height: 413px;
        @include breakpoint(xsmin) {
          height: 213px;
        }
      }
    }
```

```html
     <div class="row practice-areas">
      <div class="row practice-areas">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <div class="col-lg-4 square-1">
            <div class="left">
              <h1 class="amount">$90.2</h1>
              <p class="million">million</p>
              <p class="result">text</p>
            </div>
            <div class="right">
              <h5 class="case">COMPANY NAME</h5>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 square-2">
            <h1>$90.2</h1>
            <p>million</p>
            <p class="result">company</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 square-3">
            <h1>$90.2</h1>
            <p>million</p>
            <p class="result">COMPANY</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use bootstrap V3 then it will be like this. I don't know what are you use Bootstrap 3 or 4. Also your `HTML` structure isn't correct.

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300,700");
.practice-areas h1 {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed';
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #ffffff;
  line-height: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 0;
  text-align: right;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.practice-areas h5 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed';
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  text-align: left;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.practice-areas p {
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed';
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  text-align: right;
  color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.practice-areas .result {
  color: #f6f6f6;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.practice-areas .square-1 {
  background-image: url("https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&w=350&h=150");
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 300px;
}

.practice-areas .square-2 {
  background-image: url("https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&w=350&h=150");
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 300px;
}

.practice-areas .square-3 {
  background-image: url("https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&w=350&h=150");
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 300px;
}

.practice-areas .square {
  bottom: 20px;
  display: table;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.practice-areas .square-1,
.practice-areas .square-2,
.practice-areas .square-3 {
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  -o-transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.practice-areas .square-1:hover, .practice-areas .square-1:focus,
.practice-areas .square-2:hover,
.practice-areas .square-2:focus,
.practice-areas .square-3:hover,
.practice-areas .square-3:focus {
  background-color: #FAE2E1;
  background-image: none;
}

.practice-areas .square-1 .left,
.practice-areas .square-1 .right,
.practice-areas .square-2 .left,
.practice-areas .square-2 .right,
.practice-areas .square-3 .left,
.practice-areas .square-3 .right {
  display: table-cell;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 50%;
}

.practice-areas .square-1 .left,
.practice-areas .square-2 .left,
.practice-areas .square-3 .left {
  border-right: 1px solid #ffffff;
}

.practice-areas .square-1 .right,
.practice-areas .square-2 .right,
.practice-areas .square-3 .right {
  border-left: 1px solid #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row practice-areas">
    <div class="col-sm-4 square-1">
      <div class="square">
        <div class="left">
          <h1 class="amount">$90.2</h1>
          <p class="million">million</p>
          <p class="result">text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
          <h5 class="case">COMPANY NAME</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 square-2">
      <div class="square">
        <div class="left">
          <h1 class="amount">$90.2</h1>
          <p class="million">million</p>
          <p class="result">text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
          <h5 class="case">COMPANY NAME</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 square-3">
      <div class="square">
        <div class="left">
          <h1 class="amount">$90.2</h1>
          <p class="million">million</p>
          <p class="result">text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
          <h5 class="case">COMPANY NAME</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Rahul, that did it!

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox to the rescue. I structured each section as shown below. The rest was applied via css.

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="left">
        <h1 class="amount">$90.2</h1>
        <p class="million">million</p>
        <p class="result">text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <h5 class="case">COMPANY NAME</h5>
        <p class="lipsum">lipsum</p>
        <p class="date">date</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ke5octvj/

Comment: This is working correctly in the fiddle, but when I bring it over to my page, the text is still misaligned. I've removed all other css, and still having the issue. I've also added an image to the background, but they aren't showing up: https://jsfiddle.net/ke5octvj/1/

Comment: It acts as it should for me. You have to be more specific when you say something like "misaligned". That tells me nothing. What's misaligned? Vertically, horizontally?

Comment: You can set the css to scss.

Comment: Well, when I undid the nesting it worked as it should. I'm glad to look into alignment if you clarify what's actually not aligning and how.

Comment: This is how it's looking when I add your updates to the page: https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/ftp-assets/Screen+Shot+2017-01-26+at+1.39.53+PM.png There aren't any overriding classes that I can see.

Comment: Is it live somewhere I can debug?

Comment: Serg - Thanks for all your help and patience. Rahul's solution fixed my issues.

Comment: Too bad there's no way to give points/credit for guiding in the right direction :(